# SELECT INTO with an additional column

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am attempting to insert a copy of a row from one table into another table with the same schema, with the addition of one column (a timestamp) to provide a "history" of the first table in MS Sql Server 2005.

So, my query, without the additional column would be:

```
"SELECT INTO [WebsiteHistory] FROM [Website]"
```

I want to populate the timestamp column as well, but am not sure how to best do this. I'd like to do something like:

```
"SELECT Website.*, '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "' INTO [WebsiteHistory] FROM [Website]"
```

But that shouldn't work, especially if the timestamp column is not the last one. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Never be implicit. Adding a column to a table shouldn't break code but it would break your code.

Comment: It's best to let these things happen on the SQL server, for example through an ON UPDATE trigger. This way you don't have do bother in your application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be warned. This works, but it is neither *nice* nor recommendable:

```
INSERT
  WebsiteHistory
SELECT
  *,
  GETDATE()
FROM
  Website
WHERE
  Id = @WebsiteId
```

This assumes `WebsiteHistory` has the same structure as `Website` (you said it has), plus there is one additional `DATETIME` field.

Better is this, because it is much more fail-safe (at the expense of being more verbose):

```
INSERT
  WebsiteHistory
  (
  Id,
  Field1,
  Field2,
  Field3,
  Field4,
  ModifiedDate
  )
SELECT
  Id,
  Field1,
  Field2,
  Field3,
  Field4,
  GETDATE()
FROM
  Website
WHERE
  Id = @WebsiteId
```

Comment: Since when is being verbose bad?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a timestamp column with a default constraint on it to automatically populate it when a row is added to the table?

Comment: That would be another way to do it, maybe even more elegant. But I would have needed to go into more detail to explain something that would not have made the solution *more correct* than it is right now.

Comment: While the auto-populated timestamp column would certainly work, I was as interested in the best way to address this general scenario (needing to copy all the columns but with some arbitrary additions) as I was with this specific case (needing a timestamp column).

Comment: Please stop referring to it as a timestamp column, in SQL Server a timestamp column does not store dates and times. It is a datetime column you need.  Yes a constraint would be the best way to ensure the data alawys got populated in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you set a default constraint on the column that would automatically populate the timestamp column when a row is inserted to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the accepted answer for this question: [Dynamically look up column names for a table while in an sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205950/dynamically-look-up-column-names-for-a-table-while-in-an-sql-query)

It fetches the names of all the fields in the table to create a query customized to that table. You should be able to simply adapt the exact same technique to generate the right fields names here.